# php form only sending blank emails

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

Hi there I am having some trouble getting my php form to actually forward the information that is put in.

I have been struggling for a couple of days now and researched a lot online but unfortunately haven't found the answer.

The form works and redirects with a success message, is sent to my websites email then forwarded to a personal email. This is all instant but I only seem to receive blank emails.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

  $from = "admin@abievetattoo.com";
  $to = "abievetattoo@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Booking Enquiry";
  $cf_name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['cf_name'])); 
  $cf_email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['cf_email'])); 
  $cf_message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['cf_message'])); 

  $validationOK=true;
  if (!$validationOK) {
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
    exit;
  }

  $Body  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $Body .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $Body .= 'From: '. $from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  $Body = "";
  $Body = "Name: ";
  $Body = $cf_name;
  $Body = "\n";
  $Body = "eMail: ";
  $Body = $cf_email;
  $Body = "\n";
  $Body = "Message: ";
  $Body = $cf_message;
  $Body = "\n";

  $success = mail($to, $subject, $Body, "From: $from" . "\r\n");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Thank you for the message. Abi will respond shortly.");
  window.location = 'http://abievetattoo.com/contact.html';
</script>
```

Here is the html code:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <p>Your name</p>
    <input type="text" name="cf_name" required>
    <br>
    <p>Your e-mail</p>
    <input type="email" name="cf_email" required>
    <br>
    <p>Message</p>
    <input type="text" name="cf_message">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're using `$Body = "\n";` throughout. That's setting the value, not concatenating to it, so your final email body is just a `\n`. Try `$Body .= "\n";` - note the full stop before the equals.

Comment: Also, lines like `Mime-Version:` and `Content-type` should be in the header, not the body.

Comment: you're not concatenating throughout, you're overwriting (wrt $body)

Comment: and even if you were concatenating properly, you're mixing headers and the body together, which is ALSO wrong. headers are separate for a reason.

Comment: If you just have `$validationOK=true;` it will always be `true`. So you'll never see `if (!$validationOK) {`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe it was a simple fix like that.